# Changing HttpURLConnection in running jvm

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, sun

Is it possible to change the http handler in jax-ws?
For example: from weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection to sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Take a look at http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html, which supports HttpURLConnection and Apache HTTPClient. You may be able to use http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html with it. Also you shouldn't use classes from package sun.* since they can be removed any time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try to using `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` in the weblogic.

**manage weblogic by using WLST (non-clustered)**

add  jvm arguments in the managered server env script under `$WLS_DOMAIN_HOME/bin/setDomainEnv.sh`

```
  JAVA_OPTIONS=-DUseSunHttpHandler=true 
  export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

**manage weblogic by using Weblogic console (Clustered)**

Add `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` to Arguments in a or b.

- In Admin Console navigate to `Home`  > `Summary of Servers`  > `<managed server name>` > `Configuration` >  `Server Start` Tab.
- In the config file  `$WLS_DOMAIN_HOME/config/config.xml` with xml-path `server` > `server-start` > `arguments`

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own `URLConnectionFactory`, which resturns the desired `HttpURLConnection` and set it when constructing the **Jersey** Client.

```
URLConnectionClientHandler urlConnectionClientHandler = new URLConnectionClientHandler(
    new MyURLConnectionFactory());
Client client = new Client(urlConnectionClientHandler);
```